# Split string when ";" appears

Tags: python, string

I need to split the string everytime `;` shows up.

```
words = "LightOn;LightOff;LightStatus;LightClientHello;"
```

Output should be something like this:

```
LightOn
LightOff
LightStatus
LightClientHello
```

Simply, everytime it finds `;` in a string, it has to split it.

Thank you for help

Comment: The solution to this is extremely simple - look inside Python docs for `.split()`.

Comment: `words.split(';')`?

Comment: `words.split` is not giving me the output I need.

Comment: Ok, got it already.

Answer (score 1):

```
res = words.split(";")
```

Refer to [this link](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dictionary/python-split) for more information on split.